# Clickhouse. Cannot alter settings, because table engine doesn't support settings changes

Tags: clickhouse

If I create table:

```
    │ CREATE TABLE default.graphite
(
    `Path` String,
    `Value` Float64,
    `Time` UInt32,
    `Date` Date,
    `Timestamp` UInt32
)
ENGINE = GraphiteMergeTree('graphite_rollup')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Date)
ORDER BY (Path, Time)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

I can: ALTER TABLE graphite MODIFY SETTING storage_policy = '???';

But if my table created:

```
│ CREATE TABLE graphite
(
    `Path` String,
    `Value` Float64,
    `Time` UInt32,
    `Date` Date,
    `Timestamp` UInt32
)
ENGINE = GraphiteMergeTree(Date, (Path, Time), 8192, 'graphite_rollup') │
```

I can't =(
I recieve error: DB::Exception: Cannot alter settings, because table engine doesn't support settings changes.

Help me, how I can change settin?

└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Comment: As I understand it, I use deprecated method the table creation . And i need change it. But I don't know how yet.  https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/graphitemergetree

Comment: yes, tables with the depricated syntax does not support it.

Comment: @DennyCrane is true, you must (re)define the table with a new syntax, actually, recreate it. Maybe this can help to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716267/is-it-possible-to-change-a-table-engine-of-an-existed-clickhouse-table

Comment: @gelin it will not help.

Answer (score 0):

It was decided to create a table with a new syntax and transfer data to it