# Clickhouse GraphiteMergeTree Table migrate from deprecated format_version

Tags: clickhouse

I tried 2 ways described here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716267/is-it-possible-to-change-a-table-engine-of-an-existed-clickhouse-table)

1. Edit metadata file

   CREATE TABLE graphite.data_test
   (
   `Path` String,
   `Value` Float64,
   `Time` UInt32,
   `Date` Date,
   `Timestamp` UInt32
   )
   ENGINE = GraphiteMergeTree(Date, (Path, Time), 8192, 'graphite_rollup')

   alter table graphite.data_test attach partition 202208 from graphite.data;

   detach table graphite.data_test;

   vi /var/lib/clickhouse/metadata/graphite/data_test.sql
   ATTACH TABLE data_test
   (
   `Path` String,
   `Value` Float64,
   `Time` UInt32,
   `Date` Date,
   `Timestamp` UInt32
   )
   ENGINE = GraphiteMergeTree('graphite_rollup')
   PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Date)
   ORDER BY (Path, Time)
   SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

   attach table graphite.data_test;

ERROR: MergeTree data format version on disk doesn't support custom partitioning.

2. Copy partitions

   CREATE TABLE data_test
   (
   `Path` String,
   `Value` Float64,
   `Time` UInt32,
   `Date` Date,
   `Timestamp` UInt32
   )
   ENGINE = GraphiteMergeTree('graphite_rollup')
   PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Date)
   ORDER BY (Path, Time)
   SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

   alter table graphite.data_test attach partition 202208 from graphite.data;

ERROR: Tables have different format_version.

Can you tell me if there is any workaround, a way to change the deprecate table to a new format?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible only using console app and only for parts (not tables) and you need to build this app by yourself.

this app has different names (dependent on version) convert-parts-from-old-format / convert-month-partitioned-parts